# Multiple Bars Above another with offset

Tags: core-plot

Hi there i´m trying to present a bar plot with multiple bars. Each bar consists of multiple (but same amount for every bar) subsections. So i want to show a bar which has a lower part (e.g. green) a middle part (e.g. yellow) and the top red part. I thought about creating three independent plot but this would bring some overhead since the order drawing isn´t fix i guess
(the time when respective datasource will be called is unknown and the smalles bar could be covered by a bigger one).

So i was thinking about giving each bar an offset to affiliate the lower bar. 
But how do i dynamically add an y-offset to a bar location?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `barBasesVary` property on your plots to YES. Core Plot will then query your datasource for an additional field called `CPBarPlotFieldBarBase` for each data point. This means you will provide three data values for each bar--location, base value, and tip value.